# Getting SQLite to delete all records in a table

Tags: java, database, sqlite

I’m trying to delete all records in my `MAIN_TABLE` in my database located in my C:/ drive.. I’m using `SQLite` and I’m not on the `Android` platform. I’ve only seen `TURNCATE` used in a couple of examples so I’m not 100% sure that is right..

**CODE:**

```
package Exporter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class DeleteAllRecords { 
//public void   runDeleteAllRecords()throws Exception, SQLException {
  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

String driverName = "org.sqlite.JDBC";
Class.forName(driverName);

String url = ("jdbc:sqlite:" + "C:/Test/DATABASE.db");
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();

String sql = "TRUNCATE MAIN_TABLE";
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
sql = "DELETE FROM MAIN_TABLE";
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
}
}
```

**ERRORS:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: near "TRUNCATE": syntax error
at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.throwex(NativeDB.java:397)
at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB._exec(Native Method)
at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Statement.executeUpdate(JDBC3Statement.java:116)
at Exporter.DeleteAllRecords.main(DeleteAllRecords.java:21)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SQLite does not have an actual `TRUNCATE` command.  Rather it has a truncate optimizer which will be used whenever you run `DELETE` without a `WHERE` clause.  So you should just use `DELETE FROM` without a `WHERE` clause to truncate your table:

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM MAIN_TABLE";
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

From the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html):

> **The Truncate Optimization**
>
> When the WHERE is omitted from a DELETE statement and the table being deleted has no triggers, SQLite uses an optimization to erase the entire table content without having to visit each row of the table individually. This "truncate" optimization makes the delete run much faster.

Answer (score 3):

"DELETE FROM MAIN_TABLE" maybe is not enough. Your data only marked as deleted but physically still in database file.

If you want zeros in place of your old data - you need second command
"VACUUM".

approximate code:

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM MAIN_TABLE";
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
sql = "VACUUM";
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.execSQL("delete from "+ TABLENAME);
```

don't put star